# Can't load cryptodev-module from Yocto build

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying install cryptodev-module from my Yocto build. I build cryptodev-module with this command:

`bitbake cryptodev-module`

after that I've got rpm packages and installed them:

cryptodev-module-1.11-r0.rpm
cryptodev-module-dbg-1.11-r0.rpm
cryptodev-module-dev-1.11-r0.rpm
kernel-module-cryptodev-4.19.78-1.11-r0.rpm

But then I tried to load cryptodev-module `modprobe -f cryptodev-module` I got error:

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'cryptodev': Exec format error`

modinfo output cryptodev-module:

```
modinfo cryptodev
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.78/extra/cryptodev.ko
license:        GPL
description:    CryptoDev driver
author:         Nikos Mavrogiannopoulos <nmav@gnutls.org>
depends:        
name:           cryptodev
vermagic:       4.19.78 preempt mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8 
parm:           cryptodev_verbosity:0: normal, 1: verbose, 2: debug (int)
```

Another driver that I can load:

```
modinfo 8188eu
filename:       /lib/modules/4.19.78/extra/8188eu.ko
version:        v5.3.9_28540.20180627
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
depends:        cfg80211
name:           8188eu
vermagic:       4.19.78 preempt mod_unload ARMv7 thumb2 p2v8
```

Comment: Command to install cryptodev-module: ```rpm -i <package>```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need set ARM_INSTRUCTION_SET = "thumb" in your local.conf